# Why is this nested LinearLayout not working?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to nest a LinearLayout inside a LinearLayout.

Here is my Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ABC"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ABC"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The idea was to have a LinearLayout that is vertical, so, enabling me to have a bunch of rows.

Each row would consist of a label followed by a textbox.. or rather, a TextView followed by an EditText

So within a Vertical LinearLayout i'd nest multiple Horizontal LinearLayout objects.. That was the idea. But it hasn't worked.

Currently I have
[image]

I want and expect my code to produce a second row

But the second row isn't appearing.

My second horizontal LinearLayout, (the second of my nested LinearLayout objects, doesn't seem to be having any effect.

Comment: Try to replace the `android:layout_height` properties of your "second level" `LinearLayout`s to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Both of your layouts have android:layout_height="fill_parent" so only one of them can be visible at a time (It's taking up all the space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` on your first children `LinearLayout` use the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you fill_parent on height in your children rows. Just use wrap_content, or give a fixed (dp) height value for each "row", or you can use weightSum and give 0dp for each of your rows height. 
Note: The documentation says that you should avoid nested linear layouts because of bad performance.